# Set Focus to formField1

Tags: vba, excel

I am in need of a little help. I creater a UserForm and am attempting to get the form (on one worksheet) to write to another worksheet. I feel like I am getting close but I keep getting the following error:

I keep getting the Run-time 2110 Error in excel.

Beyond that I am trying to get the data in my userform to post to a worksheet titled Hourly CI Data.

The following code is from my UserForm object:

```
Private Sub cmdbtnCancel_Click()
' Clear data fields and reset the form
Me.formField1.Value = ""
Me.formField2.Value = ""
Me.formField3.Value = ""
Me.formField4.Value = ""
Me.formField5.Value = ""
Me.formField6.Value = ""
Me.formField7.Value = ""
Me.formField8.Value = ""
Me.formField9.Value = ""
Me.formField10.Value = ""
Me.formField11.Value = ""
Me.formField1.SetFocus
Unload Me
End Sub

Sub cmdbtnSave_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Unload Me
Set ws = Worksheets("Hourly Slot CI - Data")
' Find the next empty row
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
' Input the data in the Data Table
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.formField1.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.formField2.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.formField3.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.formField4.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.formField5.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.formField6.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.formField7.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.formField8.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.formField9.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.formField10.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.formField11.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Me.formField12.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.formField13.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Me.formField14.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.formField15.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.formField16.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Me.formField17.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 18).Value = Me.formField18.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 19).Value = Me.formField19.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 20).Value = Me.formField20.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 21).Value = Me.formField21.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 22).Value = Me.formField22.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 23).Value = Me.formField23.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 24).Value = Me.formField24.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 25).Value = Me.formField25.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 26).Value = Me.formField26.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 27).Value = Me.formField27.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 28).Value = Me.formField28.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 29).Value = Me.formField29.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 30).Value = Me.formField30.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 31).Value = Me.formField31.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Activate
' Clear all fields and reset the form
Me.formField1.Value = ""
Me.formField2.Value = ""
Me.formField3.Value = ""
Me.formField4.Value = ""
Me.formField5.Value = ""
Me.formField6.Value = ""
Me.formField7.Value = ""
Me.formField8.Value = ""
Me.formField9.Value = ""
Me.formField10.Value = ""
Me.formField11.Value = ""
Me.formField12.Value = ""
Me.formField13.Value = ""
Me.formField14.Value = ""
Me.formField15.Value = ""
Me.formField16.Value = ""
Me.formField17.Value = ""
Me.formField18.Value = ""
Me.formField19.Value = ""
Me.formField20.Value = ""
Me.formField21.Value = ""
Me.formField22.Value = ""
Me.formField23.Value = ""
Me.formField24.Value = ""
Me.formField25.Value = ""
Me.formField26.Value = ""
Me.formField27.Value = ""
Me.formField28.Value = ""
Me.formField29.Value = ""
Me.formField30.Value = ""
Me.formField31.Value = ""
Me.formField1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

I am unsure on exactly how to set this focus correctly so any input is helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So, it works other than the `Me.formField1.SetFocus` line?  The data is written and the form clears out?

Comment: Try moving the Unload Me statement to after the SetFocus statement in the cmdbtnSave_Click() macro. Also, it may be preferable to clear the form fields when you open the form rather than when you close it

Comment: What do you have to initialize the userform? If the Cancel means to reset the userform, why not call it at the end instead of unload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unloading the form before you actually try to set the values. You need to unload the form after you're completely done with it at the very end. In your case, on the `CmdbtnSave_Click` sub, you'd want to put it right before `End Sub`, and make sure you remove it towards the beginning.

EDIT: Also, if you're unloading the form, you shouldn't need to clear out the different formfields. Unloading will remove it(and the formfield values) from the computer's memory.